# Unique Solution in (0,1) - or, extinction probability

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, regression

I am interested in the unique solution to:
$$x=(1-\frac{1+a}{n}+\frac{x(1+a)}{n})^n,  (1)$$
such that $x\in(0,1)$. Specifically, I am interested in the case where $n\to\infty$.

I know that this is the extinction probability of $Bin[n,\frac{1+a}{n}]$-Galton-Watson tree, therefore I know that the solution should be $$1-\frac{2a-2a^2/3+O(a^4)}{1+a}. (2)$$
Furthermore, I know I can express $(1)$ by:
$$x=e^{(x-1)(1+a)}. (3)$$.

And still, I don't understand - how do we get from $(3)$ to $(2)$? How do we approach $(3)$?

I am weakly familiar with the Lambert function - is this the idea here? How do we use it?

Comment: Is the solution of $(1)$ your real concern ? Interesting problem ! Just out of curiosity, did you already got results ? I am very interested by this problem. Cheers :)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes. As a matter of fact, $a$ I am concerned with is rather small, so this approximation is good enough. The problem comes from considering a well-connected random graph (or even a good jumbled graph), and then eliminating most of its edges (randomly, i.i.d bernoulli - i.e. bond percolation). We are then interested in the new graph, and the extinction/survival probability is one approach to study it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with $(3)$
$$x=e^{(x-1)(1+a)}$$ the solution is given by
$$x=-\frac 1{1+a}W\left(-(1+a)\, e^{-(1+a)}\right)$$ Expanding as series around $a=0$ (assuming $a>0$)
$$W\left(-(1+a)\, e^{-(1+a)}\right)=-1+a-\frac{2 }{3}a^2+\frac{4 }{9}a^3-\frac{44 }{135}a^4+O\left(a^5\right)$$ making
$$x=\frac{1-a+\frac{2 }{3}a^2-\frac{4 }{9}a^3+\frac{44 }{135}a^4+O\left(a^5\right) } {1+a}$$ or
$$x=1-\frac{2 a-\frac{2 }{3}a^2+\frac{4 }{9}a^3-\frac{44 }{135}a^4+O\left(a^5\right) }{1+a}$$ wich is $(2)$.

**Edit**

This approximation is not very good (even very bad when $a>\frac 12$). You could have a much better one using a Padé approximant to obtain
$$x=-\frac{2 b^3-18 b^2+45 b+16}{3 b\left(6 b^2+8 b+1\right)}\qquad \text{where} \qquad b=1+a$$ If you want much better ones, just tell me.

**Details about the series expansion**

For the expansion of
$$W\left(-(1+a)\, e^{-(1+a)}\right)$$ around $a=0$, start with

$$-(1+a)\, e^{-(1+a)}=-\frac 1e+\frac 1e\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n}\frac{ (n!-(n-1)!)}{ (n-1)! n!}a^n$$ that you can truncate whereever you want.

Now, around $t=-\frac1e$,
$$W(t)=-1+x-\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{11 x^3}{72}-\frac{43 x^4}{540}+\frac{769
   x^5}{17280}-\frac{221 x^6}{8505}+O\left(x^7\right)$$ where $x=\sqrt{2(1+et)}$.

Combining both expansions

$$W\left(-(1+a)\, e^{-(1+a)}\right)=-1+a-\frac{2 a^2}{3}+\frac{4 a^3}{9}-\frac{44 a^4}{135}+\frac{104
   a^5}{405}-\frac{40 a^6}{189}+O\left(a^7\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much. One small question, if I may - how did you expand the Lambert function?

Comment: @Studentmath. Composition of Taylor series. I shall try to edit. Cheers :-)